# SELECT clause in Cassandra CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I need to run the following query (SQL syntax)

```
select AGGREGATE_NAME AS NAME, KEYSPACE_NAME from SYSTEM_SCHEMA.AGGREGATES
UNION ALL
select TRIGGER_NAME AS NAME, KEYSPACE_NAME from SYSTEM_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
```

But, of course, Cassandra does not support UNION ALL.
How to write this in **one** query like this in Cassandra CQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're doing a UNION ALL (all rows), simply write it as two separate queries and concatenate your results. Easiest answer I can think of.

-Jim

Comment: Thanks, is that possible to do it in one query?

Comment: Not that I can think of at the top of my head.